# Openstack Horizon : alway back to login page

Tags: openstack, openstack-horizon

Opening http://mycloud/dashboard
I got 
http://mycloud/dashboard/auth/login/?next=/dashboard/

After auth succed, I got
http://mycloud/dashboard/project/

Try to click on 'API Access', I'm thrown back to login page 
http://mycloud/dashboard/auth/login/?next=/dashboard/project/api_access/

Basically, anywhere I click I always back to login page.

Below is my openstack_dashboard/local/local_settings.py

```
import os
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from horizon.utils import secret_key
from openstack_dashboard.settings import HORIZON_CONFIG
DEBUG = True
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'horizon',
        'USER': 'packstack',
        'PASSWORD': 'L3tM31n',
        'HOST': '192.168.5.80',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True
SESSION_TIMEOUT = 1800
WEBROOT = '/dashboard/'
LOGIN_URL = WEBROOT + 'auth/login/'
LOGOUT_URL = WEBROOT + 'auth/logout/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = WEBROOT
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
OPENSTACK_KEYSTONE_MULTIDOMAIN_SUPPORT = True
LOCAL_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
SECRET_KEY = secret_key.generate_or_read_from_file(
    os.path.join(LOCAL_PATH, '.secret_key_store'))
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"
CACHES = {
    'default':{
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    },
}
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
OPENSTACK_HOST = "127.0.0.1"
OPENSTACK_KEYSTONE_URL = "http://%s:7001/v3" % OPENSTACK_HOST
OPENSTACK_KEYSTONE_DEFAULT_ROLE = "_member_"
OPENSTACK_KEYSTONE_BACKEND = {
    'name': 'native',
    'can_edit_user': True,
    'can_edit_group': True,
    'can_edit_project': True,
    'can_edit_domain': True,
    'can_edit_role': True,
}
OPENSTACK_HYPERVISOR_FEATURES = {
    'can_set_mount_point': False,
    'can_set_password': False,
    'requires_keypair': False,
    'enable_quotas': True
}
OPENSTACK_CINDER_FEATURES = {
    'enable_backup': False,
}
OPENSTACK_NEUTRON_NETWORK = {
    'enable_router': True,
    'enable_quotas': True,
    'enable_ipv6': True,
    'enable_distributed_router': False,
    'enable_ha_router': False,
    'enable_fip_topology_check': True,
    'supported_vnic_types': ['*'],
    'physical_networks': [],
}
OPENSTACK_HEAT_STACK = {
    'enable_user_pass': True,
}
IMAGE_CUSTOM_PROPERTY_TITLES = {
    "architecture": _("Architecture"),
    "kernel_id": _("Kernel ID"),
    "ramdisk_id": _("Ramdisk ID"),
    "image_state": _("Euca2ools state"),
    "project_id": _("Project ID"),
    "image_type": _("Image Type"),
}
IMAGE_RESERVED_CUSTOM_PROPERTIES = []
API_RESULT_LIMIT = 1000
API_RESULT_PAGE_SIZE = 20
SWIFT_FILE_TRANSFER_CHUNK_SIZE = 512 * 1024
INSTANCE_LOG_LENGTH = 35
DROPDOWN_MAX_ITEMS = 30
TIME_ZONE = "UTC"
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'console': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s'
        },
        'operation': {
            'format': '%(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
        },
        'console': {

            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'console',
        },
        'operation': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'operation',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'horizon': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'horizon.operation_log': {
            'handlers': ['operation'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'openstack_dashboard': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'novaclient': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'cinderclient': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'keystoneauth': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'keystoneclient': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'glanceclient': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'neutronclient': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'swiftclient': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'oslo_policy': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'openstack_auth': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },


        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'requests': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'urllib3': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'chardet.charsetprober': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'iso8601': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'scss': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
SECURITY_GROUP_RULES = {
    'all_tcp': {
        'name': _('All TCP'),
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '1',
        'to_port': '65535',
    },
    'all_udp': {
        'name': _('All UDP'),
        'ip_protocol': 'udp',
        'from_port': '1',
        'to_port': '65535',
    },
    'all_icmp': {
        'name': _('All ICMP'),
        'ip_protocol': 'icmp',
        'from_port': '-1',
        'to_port': '-1',
    },
    'ssh': {
        'name': 'SSH',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '22',
        'to_port': '22',
    },
    'smtp': {
        'name': 'SMTP',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '25',
        'to_port': '25',
    },
    'dns': {
        'name': 'DNS',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '53',
        'to_port': '53',
    },
    'http': {
        'name': 'HTTP',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '80',
        'to_port': '80',
    },
    'pop3': {
        'name': 'POP3',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '110',
        'to_port': '110',
    },
    'imap': {
        'name': 'IMAP',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '143',
        'to_port': '143',
    },
    'ldap': {
        'name': 'LDAP',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '389',
        'to_port': '389',
    },
    'https': {
        'name': 'HTTPS',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '443',
        'to_port': '443',
    },
    'smtps': {
        'name': 'SMTPS',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '465',
        'to_port': '465',
    },
    'imaps': {
        'name': 'IMAPS',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '993',
        'to_port': '993',
    },
    'pop3s': {
        'name': 'POP3S',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '995',
        'to_port': '995',
    },
    'ms_sql': {
        'name': 'MS SQL',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '1433',
        'to_port': '1433',
    },
    'mysql': {
        'name': 'MYSQL',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '3306',
        'to_port': '3306',
    },
    'rdp': {
        'name': 'RDP',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '3389',
        'to_port': '3389',
    },
}
REST_API_REQUIRED_SETTINGS = ['OPENSTACK_HYPERVISOR_FEATURES',
                              'LAUNCH_INSTANCE_DEFAULTS',
                              'OPENSTACK_IMAGE_FORMATS',
                              'OPENSTACK_KEYSTONE_BACKEND',
                              'OPENSTACK_KEYSTONE_DEFAULT_DOMAIN',
                              'CREATE_IMAGE_DEFAULTS',
                              'ENFORCE_PASSWORD_CHECK']
ALLOWED_PRIVATE_SUBNET_CIDR = {'ipv4': [], 'ipv6': []}
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = WEBROOT
MEDIA_URL = WEBROOT + '/media/'
STATIC_URL = WEBROOT + '/static/'
```

Comment: What role has the user you are trying the access with? Do you see anything in the keystone logs that would point to an authentication failure?